# AVD in Android Studio terminates?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec09X.png)

I am trying to run the android emulator as you see in the in the image.
It says

> The Emulator process for AVD DEVICE NAME has terminated

Comment: Check that you have enough memory to run the emulator.

Comment: I have 4GB of Ram

Comment: 4 GB is usually not enough to run an emulator (especially if Android Studio is running along with it).